# How to put a console.log() in every function?

Tags: javascript

I would like for functions to console.log() their names whenever they run. That way I can tell which functions are running in this big plate of spaghetti code I'm eating.

So far I've got this

```
function printGlobalFunctions() {
    var PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME = "\
                   var identify_name = arguments.callee;\
                   var identify_regEx = new RegExp('.*?(?=\\\\()');\
                   identify_name = identify_regEx.exec(identify_name);\
                   identify_name = identify_name.toString();\
                   identify_name = identify_name.replace('function ', '');\
                   console.log(identify_name);"; //.*?(?=\()

    for (var prop in window) {
        if (typeof window[prop] === "function") {
            var func = window[prop].toString();
            if (/\[native code\]/.test(func) === false) {
                if (/\$/.test(prop) !== true && /jQuery/.test(prop) !== true) {
                    func = func.replace(PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME, "");
                    func = func.replace(/{/, "{" + PRINT_FUNCTION_NAME);
                    eval(prop + "=" + func);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that only prints global functions. I would like for it to print member functions and anonymous functions too. I imagine you would modify `Function.prototype` but I don't know. Overriding `Function.Prototype.Call` is not enough because only .01% of the functions are called with myFunc.call()

Comment: Ummm What are you _trying_ to do here?

Comment: Why don't you have a look at call stack? It'll show all the trace of the functions called.

Comment: seems like you're trying to find the equivalent of php's `__call` http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/php-magic-call

Comment: How about Chrome profiler?

Comment: Why do you have both `=== false` and `!== true`? Oh, and this is impossible, by the way.

Comment: The profiler lists a billion jQuery functions. I'm hoping if there is a way to print every function I will be able to find a way to exclude jQuery functions.

Comment: Instead of doing it at runtime, you could write a script to parse a JS file and build an index of the number of times each function is called in the script (not the number of times a function is called tho.)

Comment: The best you can do is to recompile the browser with this behavior, but talk about using a sledgehammer... EDIT: Andy's answer seems easier: you can write a script that adds a console.log() at the beginning of each function definition.